# Turning json variables into swift variables

Tags: json, swift

My `PHP` server-side returns a JSON like this:

```
[{"scan_status":"ok","visitorData":[{"visitorCompany":"xyl","visitorStreet":"street","visitorBranche":"health","visitorEmail":"wesweatyoushop@gmail.com","lastmodified":"2014-12-15 14:18:55"}]}]
```

Now in Swift I would like to store this data, and for this I am trying to parse the data into Swift variables, however I got stuck.

```
do {
    //check wat we get back
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves )
    let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"]
    //let vCompany = vData["visitorCompany"]
    print("Test vData: \(vData)")
}
```

This prints

```
Test vData: Optional(( { visitorStreet = street; visitorPhone = 01606478; visitorCompany = xyl; visitorBranche = Sports; visitorEmail = "health@gmail.com"; lastmodified = "2014-12-15 14:18:55"; } ))
```

but when I try to get `visitorCompany` with

```
let vCompany = vData["visitorCompany"]
```

I get a compile error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?!' with an index of type 'String'

BTW, why do we see the equals sign in swift i.e. `visitorStreet = street`?

Comment: I'd create and populate a custom class with the data returned from the PHP call... this way you can ensure you keep everything typed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the compiler doesn't know the type of your decoded objects.

Help the compiler using casting with `if let`:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves )
    if let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        if let vCompany = vData[0]["visitorCompany"] {
            print(vCompany)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"]` populates `vData` with a generic `AnyObject?`, because `Swift` can't know what kind of objects `PHP` returns in the `JSON`.

You need to do a an [optional cast](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID341) to another dictionary before you can use `vData` like you want: `jsonData[0]["visitorData"] as? [String:AnyObject]`.

And because a conditional cast returns an optional, it's best you do an [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) to unwrap that optional, resulting in a code similar to this:

```
if let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    //let vCompany = vData["visitorCompany"]
    print("Test vData: \(vData)")
}
```

Or even better, as jsonData can not be an array, or it could be an empty array (the server malfunctions and sends an invalid `json` for example), you can go even further with the validation:

```
if let items = jsonData as? [[String:AnyObject]], vData = items.first?["visitorData"] {
    //let vCompany = vData["visitorCompany"]
    print("Test vData: \(vData)")
}
```

`items = jsonData as? [[String:AnyObject]]` fails if `jsonData` is not an array, while `vData = items.first?["visitorData"]` fails if `items.first` is nil ([optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) here), or if `items.first` doesn't have a `visitorData` key.

Comment: When i try your last suggestion i get a compile error ` Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject'`

Comment: @alex I had a typo in my code, I corrected it meanwhile, the code should compile now. It should've read `jsonData`, not `jsonData[0]`, as we need to test for `jsonData`

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"]![0] as! [String:AnyObject]
```

Comment: i can't add ![0] as! [String:AnyObject] to let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"]. I am getting a compile error `Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'Int'` with combo Eric D. answer
`
    let vData = jsonData[0]["visitorData"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let vCompany = vData[0]["visitorCompany"]`

Comment: Forced unwrapping is considered code smell, and should be avoided as much as possible. Use optional binding instead